# PJSIP on Iphone OS 3.0 how to port sound?

Tags: iphone, audio

I have successfully compiled pjsip and the Siphon project (http://code.google.com/p/siphon/) and it is working good under OS 2.2.1 However It crashes as soon as I try to place a call in OS 3.0 this is because the sound is no longer working that is the ipodsound.c file... has anyone been able to port the sound for 3.0?. What has changed that it no longer works?.  I have tried asking and looking for answers in the siphon forums but no luck so far. Can anyone please point me in the right direction?. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix to crush is very simple. You have to put sound initialization into pjmedia_snd_init() Like this one:

```
PJ_DEF(pj_status_t) pjmedia_snd_init(pj_pool_factory *factory)
{
    TRACE_((THIS_FILE, "pjmedia_snd_init."));

    snd_pool_factory = factory;

    /* audio initialization only one time */
    {
        UInt32 sessionCategory = kAudioSessionCategory_PlayAndRecord;
        AudioSessionInitialize (NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL);
        AudioSessionSetProperty (kAudioSessionProperty_AudioCategory,
                           sizeof (sessionCategory),&sessionCategory);
    }

    return PJ_SUCCESS;
}
```

BTW: You need only this fix to get the audio working